# Unity - If scene name starts with

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know if there is a way how I can check if the current scene starts with "3.". I have several gamemodes with their own scenes. Gamemode 1 scenes start with "1." (e.g 1.1, 1.2, 1.3). Now I want to check if the scene is using gamemode three by saying `if(CurrentScene starts with "3.")`. How should I do this?

Comment: When you run into such problem, break your problems into pieces. First, Google how to find current scene name. There are many results out there. After that Google how to check if a string starts with some value, there are also many results out there too. Then, when you run into problems, create a post.

Comment: I find this question helpful to solve certain points of an investigation of mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if( SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name.StartsWith("3.") )
```